# Grunt Command Line Parameters

Tags: gruntjs

I have a Grunt build file. My build file has a task that looks like the following:

```
myTask: {
  options: {
    configFile: "config/default.js",
    args: {   }
  },
  dev: {
    configFile: 'config/local.js',
    options: { args: {} },
  },
  test: {
    configFile: 'config/remote.js',
    options: { args: {} }
  }
}
```

...

```
grunt.registerTask('customTask', ['myTask:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('customTask-Test', ['myTask:test']);
```

Currently, I can run the following from the command line:

```
> grunt customTask
```

Everything works fine. However, I need to add the ability to do something like this:

```
> grunt customTask --myParam=myValue
```

I need to look at the value of myParam in my "dev" task target. However, I can't figure out how to do it.
I would be happy if I could just print out the value of myParam when myTask:dev is ran. In other words,
I'd like to see the following when run

```
> grunt customTask

> grunt customTask --myParam=hello
You entered hello

> grunt customTask-Test

> grunt customTask-Test --myParam=hello
```

How do I do something like this?

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012102/grunt-command-line-arguments-not-working

Answer (score 39):

This is all explained in the [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) page.

In your case, you could get the value of `myParam` with:

```
var target = grunt.option('myParam');
```

Comment: For default arguments you can use the standard JavaScript idiom: `grunt.option('myParam') || 'defaultValue'`.

Answer (score 7):

I made an example of use, where i can pass the module where i want my css.min to be created through this command line:

```
> grunt cssmin --target=my_module
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {    
 var module = grunt.option('target'); //get value of target, my_module
 var cssminPath = 'assets/' + module + '/css/all.css';

 grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    cssmin:{
        css: {
            files: [{
                    src: [
                        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                    ],
                    dest: cssminPath
                }]
        }
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternate way: you can use the `process.argv` array, just like you can in a regular Node app.

GruntJS is, of course, built on NodeJS.

I used this technique in order to forward my Grunt command-line args to my Node process, called by `grunt-nodemon`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `process.argv` array te read the command line args from grunt

```
var args = process.argv;
runScript(args[2], args[3]);
```

the first & second arguments are the `node` command and the script name.

```
execute: {
    target: {
      options: {
         args : [arg1, arg2]
      },
      src: ['script.js']
    }
}
```

using `grunt-execute`

Comment: This was a great way for me to have my watch task in `initConfig` be different depending upon which task was being called.  I wanted to set a variable to pass into my `watch` task based on what the task was, but before running `grunt.registerTask`, there is nothing in `grunt.task.current.name`.  Thanks for posting this!

Comment: You're welcome, i'm glad to have helped someone anyway with this comment