# Device specific build with Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am developping an angular app and handling my workflow with Grunt. My app works on desktop and mobile and these different versions share almost the same code base.

However, some modules are present in the mobile version and not on the desktop one and vice versa.

This is why I would like to make conditional builds with grunt: passing a parameter like `device` with `grund build --device='mobile'`, grunt would include to proper files in the build process.

So far, all my files are defined in a config JSON which I pass on to `grunt.initConfig`:

```
var conf = {
    ...
    files: {
       js: [ 'src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.test.js' ],
       jade: [ 'src/**/*.jade', 'src/index.jade' ],
       less: [ 'src/**/*.less' ],
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to exclude for example a chat module defined in `src/chat` in my desktop build?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127586/grunt-command-line-parameters)?