# How do you pass a parameter into a grunt task?

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs

As part of my grunt:build command, I run a shell task that builds my jekyll site, commits the project, and pushes it to github. The only problem is the commit message. I'd love to be able to call grunt:build and also pass in a string which will become my commit message. But I'm not really sure how to make that work. Any thoughts?

Here are the relevant parts of my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

            shell: {

                dev: {
                    command: 'jekyll build'
                },

                build: {
                    command: [
                    'jekyll build',
                    'git commit -am "test commit"',
                    'git push origin master'
                    ].join('&&')
                }

                }

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['jshint','concat', 'uglify','sass', 'autoprefixer','shell:build']);

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt - Command Line Arguments, not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012102/grunt-command-line-arguments-not-working)

Comment: More info: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `grunt.option()` (http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option):

```
'git commit -am "' + grunt.option('commit-msg') + '"',
```

and running with: `grunt build --commit-msg="test commit"`